# How to disable a day in react-big-calendar

Tags: react-big-calendar

I'm using react-big-calendar for calendar purpose.
Now I want to disable a particular day, i.e., If Monday is holiday or something, the user can not select any event on that day.
For that I want to disable the whole day, Because of that reason, the user can't select any timeslot.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

First thing I would do is tap into your `dayPropGetter` to apply some sort of class or style, showing the user if that date is unavailable. The next thing I would do is tap into your `onSelectSlot` to check the start/end dates on selection, and just return 'false' from the method if it's outside your acceptance boundaries.